# Drag/drop in javascript - element can move by x but not y?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

So I'm trying to do a drag/drop on elements in javascript. The video tutorial I used is here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTlZ4Hs5h80. I've coded it exactly as it says and I am able to move an object by it's x value but not it's y. So, in summary, whenever I move my mouse the position of the image changes by x, but is constant for y so I can only move my image left and right, and not up and down.

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <LINK href="gameStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="main">
        <img id="bowl" src="images/bowl.gif">
        <img id="egg" src="images/egg.gif">
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gameScript2.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript file:

```
function eggIntoBowl() 
{
    function Draggable(element, dragStart, dragDrop){
        this.element = element;
        this.dragStart = dragStart;
        this.dragDrop = dragDrop;

        this.element.classList.add('draggable');

        var self = this;
        var move = function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();

            var originalX = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this).left);
            var originalY = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this).top);

            var mouseDownX = event.clientX;
            var mouseDownY = event.clientY;

            function dragEgg(event)
            {
                self.element.style.left = originalX + event.clientX - mouseDownX + "px"
                self.element.style.top = originalY + event.clientY - mouseDownY + "py"

                event.stopPropagation();
            }

            function dropEgg(event)
            {
                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragEgg, true);
                document.removeEventListener('mouseup', dropEgg, true);

                event.stopPropagation();
            }

            document.addEventListener('mouseup', dropEgg, true);
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', dragEgg, true);
        };



        this.element.addEventListener('mousedown',move,false);
    };

    var egg = document.getElementById('egg');
    var dragObject = new Draggable(egg);
};

window.addEventListener("load", eggIntoBowl, false);
```

and this is my css:

```
body{
    width: 896px; 
    height: 652px; 
    background: #fff url(images/eggsToBowlScene.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#egg{
    position:absolute;
    top:190px;
    left:56px;
}

#bowl{
    position:absolute;
    top:141px;
    left:231px;
}

.draggable:hover{
    cursor: move;
}
```

Any ideas? I can't work out what I've done wrong. I used another drag/drop tutorial in the past and the same thing happened so I tried this other one, therefore I'm guessing it has something to do with my html file or css..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `dragEgg()` method you are using "py" instead of "px". This is not meant to be an `x` and `y` value, it is short for "pixels". The browser doesn't understand what unit a "py" is so it won't move. Changing it to "px" will tell the browser how many pixels to offset on the Y axis.

```
self.element.style.top = originalY + event.clientY - mouseDownY + "px";
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using this code if you can use simply the jQuery UI draggable interacion?

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/